# how to test mail application in blackberry simulator?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I have created an email application, and now want to test in simulator. While i send the mail it saves a copy in my device outbox. but how can test really it is sending to the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [knowledge base article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Send-and-receive-email-messages-through-the-BlackBerry-Email/ta-p/445895)

---

below, there's content from the linked page:

**Details**

Sending and receiving email messages can be tested on a computer by employing a BlackBerry device simulator, ESS, POP3 and Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) email client. Please follow the instructions below to send and receive email messages.

1. Set up ESS as a local messaging server.

   - Set the ESS to use standalone mode.
   - Select POP3 and SMTP ports (Note: This step can be omitted for ESS version 4.1 and earlier).
   - Specify a desired name and email address.
   - Launch ESS.
2. Set up a POP3 or SMTP email client (i.e. Microsoft® Outlook® Express).

   - Create an email account.
   - Associate the email address specified in step 1 for this account.
   - Set both the incoming POP3 server and outgoing SMTP server as a localhost, and use the ports specified in step 1.
3. Send an email message using BlackBerry device simulator.

   - Compose and send an email message in the BlackBerry device simulator.
4. Check for the email message in the Inbox of the email account created in step 2.
5. Reply to the email message. The reply message should appear in the Inbox of the BlackBerry device simulator.

Comment: Not loading for me :(